# Simple Alexa Audioplayer Directives Using Node.js

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I'm having a problem finding simple examples that handle Alexa audioplayer events using node.js. So far, I've only been able to get the play directive to work using the following:

```
this.response.audioPlayerPlay('REPLACE_ALL', 'URL', 0);
        this.emit(':responseReady');
```

How do I stop the audio from playing? Any time I try to trigger the StopIntent during playback by saying "stop", it triggers the PauseIntent. I want to be able to stop playback and end the session, pause playback, and resume playback. I've looked at the examples on GitHub and I haven't found them very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`this.response.audioPlayerStop(); //this part will stop the audio player from playing the current stream.`

Comment: why would saying Resume works then? should not it stay stoped after audioPlayerStop() call?